# Alarm clock school bell type

Tags: software-recommendation

Looking for an Alarm Clock for Ubuntu with the following:

- **It rings once and then stops like a school bell**
- All normal alarm stuff (schedule, etc)

Comment: Ubuntu already comes with an app with all those features...

Comment: What app is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alarm Cron](https://www.electronjs.org/apps/alarm-cron) has a nice feature to make a sound (alarm) only play once and then stop

Comment: I was unable to make it play an mp3. It's still silence when alarm triggers. =(